# How to restrict people from visiting my Express.js website?

Tags: api, express, restriction, middleman

I made an API with Express.js that if you visit it or do a GET request, you will receive sats. I want to restrict it to my Netlify website/game (which is pointed to a custom domain) and so everyone else will get a 403 or something. How can I do that? I have already tried using CORS to restrict it, and it hasn’t helped, and I have searched everywhere, and there is nothing.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_authentication.htm

Comment: How would I use that? The whole reason I made the api is because I can’t secure an api key